# Are multiple modules treated as separate macro-tasks?

Tags: javascript, html, es6-modules

Imagine I have two modules that look like this:

```
<script type=“module” src="../js/module1.js"></script>
<script type=“module” src="../js/module2.js"></script>
```

None of them import from each other.

If `module1` is executed before `module2`, does that means when `module1` is popped off the call-stack (and after the micro-queue is emptied and possibly some rendering gets done) the call-stack will be empty - potentially allowing `module2` to get pushed on it? Basically, are `module1` & `module2` treated as two separate macro-tasks or are they treated as one big script?

Comment: Under which loading conditions? Are you thinking two independent modules being loaded using `async`? One module that imports another module? (it feels like the details that prompted this question are missing atm)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks for the comment, have included some details. Hope it's enough

Comment: It looks like you're missing the `async` attribute, at the very least (and probably also `defer`), which would change an answer significantly.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I was under the impression modules have `defer` attributes implicitly (search 'defer' on this site: https://javascript.info/modules-intro)

Comment: True. You still want `async` though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes they are basically treated as two "macro-tasks" even though it's not really part of the event loop yet, so they're not really queued "tasks" that would have been queued.

Your script elements being `module` scripts with no `async` attributes, we fall in [this step](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#script-processing-module-noasync-parser-inserted) of the processing model, which will add it to the [list of scripts that will execute when the document has finished parsing](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#list-of-scripts-that-will-execute-when-the-document-has-finished-parsing), which will get emptied at ["the end"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#the-end) of the processing.
The next point we want to look at is the ["run a module script"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#run-a-module-script) algorithm, which will get called "as soon as" whatever comes last between the previous script's end of execution, or the script's readiness, as part of the [Execute the script block](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#execute-the-script-block) algorithm.

From this ["run a module script"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#run-a-module-script) algorithm, we can see that at the end the browser has to

> 9. [Clean up after running script](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#clean-up-after-running-script) with settings.

And the [clean up after running](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#clean-up-after-running-script) algorithm itself does

> [...] [perform a microtask checkpoint.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#perform-a-microtask-checkpoint).

So it's very much like if they were treated as two separate tasks indeed.

Regarding the painting, it may actually happen, since at [the end](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#the-end) of parsing, when executing these scripts, the browser has to

> 1. [Spin the event loop](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#spin-the-event-loop) until the first `script`...

and that while [spinning the event loop](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#spin-the-event-loop) the browser can indeed paint.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards the spec. Nice to refer to too